# How to open a model with multiple buttons but keep the same content?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the same model to be used by different buttons to come up and still have the same content. The first button works but the second doesn't.
Is anyone able to help?

Javascript:

```
function btnHero() {
    var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("heroClass");
    var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn2");
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

    for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
        btn[i].onclick = function () {
            modal[i].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
        span[i].onclick = function () {
            modal[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    } 
    window.onclick = function () {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

This is a sample of the buttons:

```
<div class="dropContent1">
                <!--phase 2 Start-->
                <div class="drop2">
                    <a class="btn2" id="heroGK" onclick="btnHero()">Phase II: Place Heroes</a>
                </div>
                <!--phase 3 Start-->
                <div class="drop3">
                    <a class="btn2" id="cardGK" onclick="btnGKcard()">Phase III: Draw Event Cards</a>
                </div>
                <!--phase 4 start-->
                <div class="drop4">
                    <a class="btn4">Phase IV: Action Phase</a>
                    <div class="dropContent4">
                        <a>Perform Army/Hero Actions</a>
                        <a>Heal Units</a>
                        <a>Raise New Units/Armies</a>
                        <a>Place Newly Allied Armies</a>
                    </div>
                </div><!--phase 4 end-->
            </div><!--drop1-->
        </div><!--top-->
        <div class="drop1" id="player2">
            <a class="btn1" onclick="NY()">
                <img src="image/shield/Nyrond.png" alt="Nyrond" width="35" height="35" style="padding-top:5px;" />
            </a>
            <div class="dropContent1">
                <!--phase 2 Start-->
                <div class="drop2">
                    <a class="btn2" onclick="btnHero()">Phase II: Place Heroes</a>
                </div>
```

Comment: is this true? `modal.length === btn.length && modal.length === span.length`. The script assumes this is true. Maybe that is why it's failing

Comment: there is only one modal and two buttons that I want to access the same modal. How will I fix this?

Comment: then instead of `modal[i]` should be `modal[0]`

Comment: Your a legend dude that fixed it :)

Comment: Now I've got the one modal working for each type i need help with identifying which button was pressed that brought up the modal because depending on the button pressed will determine which unique button type displays for each. Is anyone able to help?